# Чекин гостей через геопозицию

Tags: ios, iphone, геолокация

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, насколько реально чеканить гостей когда они приходят в заведение и вычикинивать, когда они выходят за дверь.
Естественно с их разрешения. Вопрос чисто с точки зрения позволит ли точность геолокации iphone

Comment: Вы хотите попробовать это сделать в том случае, если гость подключился через вифи?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/

Comment: Я пока о возможности. Через вифи точности хватит? А через 3g? А без интернета?